# Superimposing a red curve on scatter points

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I want to plot the log normal distribution given a random number of inputs as blue scatter points and then I have to superimpose a red curve on them . I have managed to do the first task however when doing the super imposing part I am getting the area filled up with colour aswell :

this is what I have tried in my code after producing x and y

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(x,y,'-bx')
plt.ylabel('Log normal distribution function values for y')
plt.xlabel('X, the generated random points from 0-10')
plt.show()
```

where x and y are generated this way :

```
for i in range(0,10000):
    x[i] = 10*random.random()
    y[i]= (1/(x[i]*sigma*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))) * math.exp(-(((math.log(x[i])- mew))**2)/(2*((sigma)**2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, unrelated to the main point of your question, you really should avoid using loops for stuff like this. Instead, try something like the following

```
sigma = 2
mew = 3
x = 10*random.random(100)
y= (1/(x*sigma*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))) * np.exp(-(((np.log(x)- mew))**2)/(2*((sigma)**2)))
```

(Change `sigma`, `mew`, and 100 to whatever you like.)

(Oh, another thing: unless you're a cat, you probably meant `mu`, not `mew`.)

Now, you can do

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
hold(True)
plt.plot(x[np.argsort(x)], y[np.argsort(x)], 'r-')
plt.ylabel('Log normal distribution function values for y')
plt.xlabel('X, the generated random points from 0-10')
hold(False)
```

(Note that for `plot`, you should sort `x` and `y`.)

This gives something like this:

[image]